# Is this an example of javascript callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I only want to know if this can be an example of javascript callback function:

```
function doing_stuff(str,callback) //external *asynchronous* function
    {
    if(confirm(str)) callback(true);
    else callback(false);
    }

function main_func() //main function
{
var to_be_sent='NONE'; //return value set with default

var callback = function callback(r) //funzione di callback
{
to_be_sent=r;
}

doing_stuff('Sure?',callback); //external function call with *callback*

return to_be_sent;
}
```

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia page for callbacks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to understand the concept of a callback.

> In computer programming, a callback is a **piece of executable code** that is **passed as an argument** to **other code**, which **is expected to call back (execute) the argument** at some convenient time. The invocation may be immediate as in a **synchronous callback**, or it might happen at a later time as in an **asynchronous callback**.

In Javascript, "a piece of executable code" can be wrapped inside a **function**. Functions in javascript are [First-Class Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), which means you can treat them like any other value, executing operations over and passing them as parameters.

Meanwhile callbacks can be synchronous, they make more sense when are called **asynchronously**. Basically you are saying:

> Hey dude, do your thing, take your time, but whenever you finish processing, please execute this piece of code.

---

So, answering your question:

**YES, you have an example of callback usage.**